# In Excel I have two columns that equal a third column but they don't equal each other. How do I get them to equal each other?

Tags: excel

In Excel I have two columns that equal a third column.  How do I get the first two to correspond to each other?  Listed below is a small example.  Sorry I didn't know to properly paste the Excel into this post.  As you can see I have Columns A-E with the titles UPC, Barcode, RMSID, UPC and Barcode.  Columns A and D are the same value of a UPC.  Both B and C correspond to the UPC column or A and D.  I want B and C to correspond to each other since they both share the value of A or D. So if C and D correspond to each other then B does also and I want this to show in Column E.  How do I write this in Excel?

```
A               B       C       D               E
UPC         Barcode RMSID   UPC             Barcode
834135001034    102432  883 892773000857    105422
892773000864    105423  884 818780010016    106487
892773000604    105421  888 892773000864    105423
892773000857    105422  900 892773000604    105421
818780010016    106487  910 834135001034    102432
```

Comment: all your numbers appear to be unique... can you give 1 line of example data you would like as output in Column E?

Comment: Can the UPC number appear more than once in column D or is it unique?  Same question for column A.  Trying to figure out how things match up based on the example data you have presented, and it is difficult.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by your statement that a UPS number "is 1".  1 what?

Comment: Sorry can only edit the comment in 5 mins and ran out if time. 834135001034 is 1  for RMSID and  834135001034 is 102432 for Barcode.  So I want Column E to show the Barcode

Comment: In what way do the values in B and C "share" the value of A or D? What is the logic/rule that ties them together? I also fail to see how A and D are the same value. Explain how in any of these rows the value is the same in A and D

Comment: Edit your question. Then post a comment. Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: `834135001034 is 1 for RMSID` what does that mean?

Comment: UPC number is unique but it can appear more than once.  UPC corresponds to both Barcode and RMSID.  RMSID and Barcode are different numbers but they are associated witha unique UPC.

Comment: A number cannot be unique and appear more than once in the same column.

Comment: Edit your question and show an example of what you need to see in one row or two rows in column E so we might be able to see a pattern

Comment: Sorry how do you paste excel columns into the question properly?

Comment: you cant cut and paste excel spreadsheets directly into the question as far as I know, you have to generate example tables just like you have.  If it is possible please, someone speak up!

Answer (score 1):

ok, this looks like a straight forward Vlookup or index/ match.  In E2 place the following formula:

```
=Vlookup(D2,$A$2:$C$6,2,0)
```

D2 is what you are looking up in the first column of A2:C6 where C6 is the bottom right corner of your data.  the 2 tells the formula to return the value in the second column.  the 0 or false tell the formula to find an exact match for what you are looking for.

you could also do this with an INDEX/MATCH combination.  It tends to be preferred as vlookup only looks up information in the left most column and can only return information to the right.  INDEX/MATCH does not have to line up vertically and the columns (or rows if you are doing horizontal lookups) can be in any order.  I would use the following:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,Match(D2,$A$2:$A$6))
```

Match will tell you what postion from the top of the A2:A6 column the value in D2 was found.  Index will then use that value to return the value in the same position from the top in column B2:B6.

When something is not found its going to spit out and error.  You can deal with that error using the IFERROR function and either have it return some text to let you know, or return an empty cell with "".  Here is one example:

```
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$C$6,2,0),"Not Found")
```

Comment: That works.  Problem solved!  I had a few that had #N/A but those were easily resolved.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GWS you may tick on the answer to credit the person. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ given this answer is about 3 years old, I have doubts its status will change to accepted